# Itertools permutations with replacement one by one

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation, python-itertools

I am trying to generate all permutations with replacement using itertools, but data is too big for RAM, so my computer goes down.

There are too many tuples, can i generate them one by one and add to file without creating all the list? Here is my code

```
from itertools import product
k = 4
n = 2
f = open('vectors.txt', 'w')
//func_val = list(product(range(k), repeat=k ** n))
for i in list(product(range(k), repeat=k ** n)):
    f.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

Comment: get rid of the `list` wrapper and let it work with generators. `for i in list(product(range(k), repeat=k ** n)):` => `for i in product(range(k), repeat=k ** n):`. List forces the result of product to be eagerly produced and all must fit in memory at once.

Comment: While you _can_ write those four billion tuples to a file, there are probably better ways to achieve whatever it is you think you need those tuples for.

Comment: thank you for answers, I am not a programmer, so do you recommend just to use generator several times ?Not to read huge data from file?

Comment: Paul's suggestion will work, assuming you have enough space on your HD to save a 200 GB file. But as DSM said, maybe you don't need to save all those tuples. What are you going to do with them?